# Custom font icons displayed incorrectly on iPhone browsers, but on any desktop looks fine

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, web, icons

I created some custom font icons and they look great on a desktop, no matter what responsive size.  The icons are the second and third.

[image]

However, on my iPhone on Chrome and Safari they look like this:

[image]

Any clue why?  I can't seem to fix it.  Location of page is here: [Website Address](https://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/14771/summer-ballin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because my font wasnt aligned as a glyph.  For some reason Illustrator to fontastic.me didnt work very well so I used Icon Moon and move the icons in their correct positions.  Fix can be found in link below.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697887/custom-font-not-replicating-font-awesome-in-website)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove top padding and increase height for mobile media query e.g

```
body.event .social-icons .btn.btn-aau
{
  padding:0;
  height:28px;
}
```

Comment: That would just mess up my desktop version then.  I dont believe it has to do with the button, because if I used just the <i></i> it does the same thing outside of the button my my table page.

Comment: you can write this under @media (max-width:767px){} so that will effect only in iphone or device which has display less then 767px