# Custom font not replicating font awesome in website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I created a custom vector font and trying to use it in some places that font awesome doesnt fit.  However the font icons dont display property like the font awesome ones do.  The CSS seems to be exact but I cant tell what is causing the issue.  Below you will see the custom icon circled, while the others are font awesome.  The icon just wont center like the font awesome icons.

You can find this markup on this page: [Vegas Finals](http://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/17690/vegas-finals)

[image]

The HTML `<i>` looks centered, but the `:before` pushes the actual icon up.

```
<i class="icon-ncaa icon-ebt-ncaa"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is that your glyphs are not centered correctly inside the custom font.

You need to edit the ***.woff*** file (*and other types if they exhibit the same problem*)

You also should remove the `btn-ncaa` class from the container `a` tag as it alters the `vertical-align` and the whole button is misplaced as well in relation to the ones next to it..

Comment: I noticed the vertical alignment, but even with that removed its not centered.  When I created the vector file for this to import into http://fontastic.me, I removed any whitespace around the font.  Are you saying I need to have a perfect square?

Comment: You are right opened in in icon moon for editing and the top part is cut off, and that is probably why its shown up a few pixels!